# PHP ZipArchive not working, no errors

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I'm trying to zip a (very large) set of files, but nothing happens and I can't seem to get *any* errors to return.

The following returns a single error, every time: #6, at the end.

Each file exists, it's readable, ZipArchive::addFile returns true, $zipArchive close()s without fail, and yet the final zip file isn't created.

What gives?

** Running this on Windows Server 2012 R2 as a local SAN, if that matters.

```
//exceptions, throws ErrorException
set_error_handler('exception_error');

try {
    // Copy directory to temporary location
    rcopy($src_location,$tmp_location);

    // Initialize archive object
    $zipArchive = new ZipArchive();
    $zipArchive->open($archive_filename, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

    // Create recursive directory iterator
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($tmp_location),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
    );

    foreach ($files as $name => $file) {
        // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
        if (!$file->isDir()) {
            // Get real and relative path for current file
            $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
            $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($tmp_location) + 1);

            if (!file_exists($filePath)) {
                _log(1,'Uploading Archives [Compression Error #1]','File Not Found ['.$filePath.']');
                throw new Exception('Giving Up');
            }
            elseif (!is_readable($filePath)) {
                _log(1,'Uploading Archives [Compression Error #2]','File Not Readable ['.$filePath.']');
                throw new Exception('Giving Up');
            }
            else {
                // Add current file to archive
                if (!$zipArchive->addFile($filePath, $relativePath)) {
                    _log(1,'Uploading Archives [Compression Error #7]','File Not Added ['.$filePath.' | '.$relativePath.']');
                    throw new Exception('Giving Up');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Zip archive will be created only after closing object
    if (!$zipArchive->close()) {
        _log(1,'Uploading Archives [Compression Error #3]','Zip Not Created ['.$zipArchive->getStatusString().']');
    }
}
catch (ErrorException $e) {
    _log(1,'Uploading Archives [Copy/Compression Error #4]',(string)$e);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    _log(1,'Uploading Archives [Copy/Compression Error #5]',(string)$e);
}
finally {
    // Clean Up Memory
    unset($files);
    unset($zipArchive);
}

// Final Check
if (!file_exists($archive_filename)) {
    _log(1,'Uploading Archives [Compression Error #6]','Error Creating Archive ['.$archive_filename.'] ('.$src_location.')');
}
```

Comment: Could it be possibly timing out?

Comment: Nope, not timing out. It runs through this code for eight or ten archives and logs the same error #6 every time. It also finishes code below this. Peak memory at roughly 2935408, which is well below my threshold.

Comment: Watching the script run...

The source directory is copied to a temporary directory "5.tmp/" at 5.12GB
Then 5.zip.a01612 is created. It begins at 0B, but fills up as the script runs... watching it reach 3GB... And then when it reaches completion (I'm assuming at ->close()), the file disappears. Poof.

[[ No idea about the a01612 extention, not my doing; that appears to be in the functionality of ZipArchive. ]]

Thoughts?

Comment: Is this Fat32 drive? File size limits?

Comment: NTFS; the files exist in the same location as where they're being compressed.